# pass an input text into parameter

Tags: javascript, html, function, parameters

i have an input text , and i want when i click in a button it takes that value and pass it in a parameter in a url , this is my code so far :

```
<div id="landmark-1" data-landmark-id="1">
    <form  name ="data">
        <label>enter your name :</label>
        <input type= "text"  placeholder="ID" name="ID" value="" style="width:206px;"  />
        <input type="submit"  value="Suivant" onclick="showUser(this.form)" >
     </form>    
</div>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
```

and this is my javascript code :

```
<script>
function showUser(frm)
{
    var str = frm.ID.value;
    if (str==""){
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/filename/page.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

but when i enter a name, it just add : ?ID=name in the url of the current page ! it doesn't send the parameter in the url i want ..

Comment: Try: var str = frm.elements['ID'].value;

Comment: the same thing, it passes in the url of the current page : ?ID=name

Comment: instead of `"http://localhost/filename/page.php?q="+str` try `"http://localhost/filename/page.php"+str`

Comment: no, @collapsar, i need that q variable in my php folder so i can make the sql requests ..

Comment: use [fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com) to find out what the request sent to the server and its response actually look like.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from: o`nclick="showUser(this.form)"` to `onclick="return showUser(this.form)"`

and

```
if (str==""){
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
}
```

to
    if (str==""){
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return false;
    }

Your form is being submitted even if there is no ID entered. The return false prevents the form submission.

Comment: I've add those changes , now i don't get the ?id thing .. but it still don't send the paramter to the localhost url ?!

Comment: Add return false after the xmlhttp.send(); as the page is still being submitted. If this still fails then you might want to check the readyState and status to see if there are errors occurring within the php file that you are not capturing.

Comment: php file is working fine , but this one it doesn't send me tha parametre i want form the input text field ! will , this is the code where i've captured this : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: please @jeff if you found something i'm really stuck in this

Answer (score 0):

Here is a revised AJAX call. It is a bit more complicated than the w3schools example but it is more functional and complete. First the AJAX routine:

```
function AJAX( url, processFunction ) {
  var XHR;
  try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari/Chrome
    XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
      XHR = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }catch (e) {
      try{
        XHR = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }catch (e){
        // Something went wrong
        alert("Your browser doesn't support AJAX!");
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  if( XHR.onreadystatechange ) {
    if( XHR.readyState == 4 ) {
      if( XHR.status == 200 ) {
        //--- we've got the data so process it
        processFunction( XHR.responseText );
      }
      if( XHR.status != "OK" ) {
        alert( 'Error : '+XHR.responseText);
      }
    }
  }
  //--- open
  XHR.open( 'GET', url ); // --- url is from the function call
  //--- send  
  XHR.send();
}
```

Now the function that will handle the returned data. In this case you simply want to display the text:

```
function processMyData( data ) {
   document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML= data;
}
```

Now for the modified showUser function

```
function showUser(frm) {
    var str = frm.ID.value;
    if (str==""){
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return false;
    } else {
      AJAX( "http://localhost/filename/page.php?q="+str, 'processMyData' )
    }
}
```

If there is an error in you php file it should show up in the alert box.

If your code still isn't returning anything and there is no error the only other thing that I can think of is that you are not echo/print-ing your data for the AJAX routine to retrieve your text.

Comment: but tell me in the w3schools example i've only change that instead of select option i put a input text !! knowing that their first example worked so good in my browser ! 
I've did your modification , but still nothing , i don't know maybe that input text has something that i need to add or something .. i'm really stuck my works depends on this

Comment: email me your page - details on my user page.